# Can I create a google form survey with option of creating a variant of answer?

Tags: google-forms, survey

I created a google form survey https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSffxQoj_nnRePpITM3OuoA03TW1TXYlGHqX-1lMAiIONUz15A/viewform?usp=sf_link . My desired result is to make it possible to make others able to add variants of choice? Like Var4, Var5 and others? Also can i see percentage of votes for each variant? If not, where can i make survey like that?

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer below if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Adding choices while on the Forms is not yet available. An alternative solution is to create an Apps Script that will add a choice once the form is submitted using [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

> To manually create an **Apps Script** within your Forms, select the horizontal 3 dot and select **Script editor**.

From there, you can create your own functions and use createChoice(value) to convert your desired value to *[Choice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice)* and use setChoices(choices) to add choices to your [Item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item).

Lastly, create an installable trigger through a dialog in the script editor.

> 1. From the script editor, choose **Edit > Current project's triggers**.
> 2. Click the link that says: **No triggers set up. Click here to add one now**.
> 3. Under **Choose which function to run**, select the name of function you want to trigger.
> 4. Under **Select event source**, select either **Time-driven** or the Google App that the script is bound to (for example, From forms).
> 5. Select and configure the event type you want to create (for example, **On form submit**).
> 6. Optionally, click **Notifications** to configure how and when you are contacted by email if your triggered function fails.
> 7. Click **Save**.

I tried to replicate the scenario and here's my code snippet:

```js
function addOption(e) {
  try {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var formResponse = e.response;
    var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
    
    //get response
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[0];
    
    //get item ID
    var id = itemResponse.getItem().getId();
    var item = form.getItemById(id).asMultipleChoiceItem();
    
    //get item choices
    var choices = item.getChoices();
    
    //convert string to choices and insert to choices array
    choices.push(item.createChoice(itemResponse.getResponse()));

    //this will remove the duplicate value generated from selecting an existing Choice.
    uniqueChoices = removeDuplicate(choices);
    uniqueItems = new Array();
    
    //create new Array of Items using the filtered array.
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueChoices.length; i++) {
      uniqueItems.push(item.createChoice(uniqueChoices[i]))
    }
    
    //set filtered array as choices.
    item.setChoices(uniqueItems);
  } catch (err) { Logger.log(err); }
}

function removeDuplicate(arrayofItems){
  var choicesValue = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayofItems.length; i++){
    choicesValue.push(arrayofItems[i].getValue());
  }
  
  return Array.from(new Set(choicesValue));
}
```

**Example Output:**

> [Initial Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCrBI.png)
>
> [Filled "Other" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KC2qo.png)
>
> [Form submitted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dVOJ5.png)
>
> ["Maybe" option is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELR0T.png)
>
> [Charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b4l8V.png)